# Laravel Eloquent Fetch all rows and their respective pivot table rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table of orders, which contain line items, which are stored in a pivot table.

Once all of the line items have been successfully processed, the order will be marked as "processed" and needs to be displayed on the page.

I therefore want to fetch all orders which have been marked as "processed" as well as the line items which are included in their respective orders.

My query looks like this:

```
$orders = DB::table('order_product')
      ->join('products', 'order_product.product_id', '=', 'products.product_id')
      ->join('orders', 'order_product.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')
      ->join('customers', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'customers.customer_id')
      ->where('order_product.variation_status', '=', 'dispatch')
      ->where('orders.store', '!=', 'null')
      ->groupBy('order_product.order_id')
      ->get();

 return response()->json($orders);
```

My thinking is to fetch all the pivot table items which are processed and then group the result by **order_id** but this unfortunately doesn't work.

I receive the following output:
[image]

Unfortunately the **variation** property only contains one line item from the pivot table, instead of two.

Can somebody help as to what I might be doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here are my models
Order.php

```
/**
     * The products that belong to the Order.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','order_product','order_id','product_id')
            ->withPivot(['qty', 'variation', 'variation_status'])
            ->withTimeStamps();
    }

    /**
     * The customer that belongs to the Order.
     */
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'customer_id');
    }
```

Product.php

```
/**
     * The orders that belong to the product.
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')
            ->withPivot(['qty', 'variation_status'])
            ->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

Comment: I recommend Eloquent to make this a lot easier. Can you give the relationships between all the used models?

Comment: Hi @LarsMertens I've added the relevant methods from my models. Does this help?

Comment: Yes I have some idea now but not sure if I can resolve it right away. I will take a look if I have some time left. Or someone else can take the credit :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee that this is correct right away because I normally don't work with `->withPivot` and have no test environment running yet so this is from the top of my head at the moment. But this might give you an insight of how to handle this usecase.

---

Let's start with order as a base

```
Order::get();
```

Now let's extend this functionality to retrieve an order with a customer and products

```
Order::with('customer', 'products')->get();
```

What we've to do now is resolving your where conditions in the above eloquent query:

```
->where('order_product.variation_status', '=', 'dispatch')
->where('orders.store', '!=', 'null')
```

What you could do is the following:

```
Order::with(['products' => function($query){
  $query->where('variation_status', 'dispatch');
}, 'customer'])
->where('store','!=','NULL')
->get();
```